# CS50 Caesar Cipher Problem: Program Produces Nothing

Tags: c, encryption, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[]){

    if(argv[2])
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
        return 1;

    for(int i = 0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++){
        if isdigit(argv[1][i]){

        }
        else{
            printf("Please only enter an integer for your key.");
            return 1;
        }
    }


    int key = (int) argv[1];

    if(key < 1){
        printf("Please only enter an integer greater than or equal to 1.");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Success: \n%i", key);


    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");


    for(int i = 0; plaintext[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if isupper(plaintext[i]){
            int character = (int) plaintext[i];
            character += (key % 26);
            character = 65 + (90 % character);
            plaintext[i] = (char) character;
        }
        else if islower(plaintext[i]){
            int character = (int) plaintext[i];
            character += (key % 26);
            character = 97 + (122 % character);
            plaintext[i] = (char) character;
        }
    }

    printf("ciphertext: %s", plaintext);


}
```

Above is my code. When I run it, it simply does not return anything. I have tried using the cs50 debugger, but for some reason it says I have changed my code every time I run it (which is false.) None of the initial error messages fire, so I don't think I am entering the argument wrong. I am entering each time "./caesar 10". Does anyone have an inkling of which part of the code is causing this?

Comment: Indent your code properly. Especially the first three lines in main.

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't even have a program to run as the code (as you currently show it) have errors that will lead to build errors.

Comment: Not to mention that you have at least one rather big misunderstanding about some basics of C (regarding casting). Please get a book or two to read from the very beginning to learn C instead.

Comment: @dgoodie This line int key = (int) argv[1]; does not make a sense. You need to use atoi or strtol

Comment: On another note, think about what happens when *no* arguments are passed to the program. Then `argv[2]` will be out of bounds and lead to undefined behavior. You should always check **`argc`** instead.

Comment: programmer dude, I think I know what you mean about casting. How can I enter the key as a string and convert that into an integer? I understand now that casting does not work that way

Comment: Lookup `atoi`...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Unfortunately `atoi` have no input validation whatsoever. Better use `strtol`.

Comment: Yeah, I should lookup the secure versions of these old C functions before I mention them.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
 if(argv[2])
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
        return 1;
```

is why the program "does nothing". Since there are no curly braces `{}` to delineate the function body, the `return 1` always executes.